# Error al utilizar Memcached con Cache API Gx15 U1 .Net

Tags: asp.net, genexus

Estoy utilizando la Genexus Cache API y al intentar obtener el valor de una clave me da una excepción de .net.

¿Por donde vendrá el problema?

Configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el log agrega:

```
DEBUG StoneFramework - StoneFramework.Caching.CacheGet|SecurityParametersType

DEBUG GeneXus.Services.GXServices - Loading STORAGE_SERVICE:D:\KBs\GProjexEv3\GP_Prototipo\web\CloudServices.config

DEBUG GeneXus.Cache.CacheFactory - Loading CACHE_PROVIDER: GeneXus.Cache.Memcached, GxMemcached, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6f5bf81c27b6b8aa

DEBUG StoneFramework - StoneFramework.Caching.CacheGet|GPARAMETERSTYPE
```

"StoneFramework.Caching.CacheGet" Se invoca previo a &Cache.Get().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, me faltaba inicializar la variable &Cache

&Cache = Cache.GetCache( !"StoneFramework" )

Answer (score 1):

Eso podría pasar si en stoneframework, esa variable &Cache sobre la que se realiza el &Cache.Get() no fue inicializada. Es decir si antes de hacer &Cache.Get no se hizo algo como esto:
&Cache = Cache.GetCache("StoneCache")

De todas maneras, sin inicializar no debería dar esa exception, es un error.